# Seperating a dataset by column value

Tags: r, dataframe

Hi all I am playing with the guinea pigs dataset in R to get a bit more skilled with manipulating datasets in R.  If you are unfamiliar the link below will explain the dataset a bit more.  But essentially the effect of vitamin c administration to guinea pigs via either orange juice or pills on length of tooth growth is displayed.  I think it comes with the Tidyverse package but it may be a present with R from the get go not sure.

https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/224098_5ca71f9a5ffb4123a9b7ca6b693db456.html

```
library(Tidyverse)
gpt=data.frame(ToothGrowth)
gpt
```

Running the above should bring up a dataframe with three columns len, supp and dose.  I think the way this is set up is not comducive to plotting and is a bad way to display the data.  We are really interested in the effects of dose via two different methods.  So we shoul really seperate the data by the supp column values of 'OJ' and 'VC' being orange juice and vitamin c respectfully, into two dataframes then merge them along their dose columns as they both share 10 measurements of length in 3 dose regimes 0.5, 1 and 2.

In summary the original data is 60 length entries by 3 columns one containing the supply methods as either 'OJ' and 'VC' and the third being three dose comditions.  I want to make a new dataframe with 3 columns dose, OJ and VC with OJ and VC containing the len entries from gpt. so it would look like this...

```
dose VC OJ
1   4.2   4.2  16.5
2  11.5   7.3  9.4
3   7.3   11.5  9.7
```

So in order to do this I want to use xtabs and merge but not sure how to do the first step.  I tried below but it just sums values I want displayed seperately.  Is xtabs a bad methods for doing what I'm trying to do?

```
> xtabs(~supp,data=gpt)
supp
OJ VC 
30 30
```

```
> xtabs(len~supp,data=gpt)
supp
   OJ    VC 
619.9 508.9
```

Comment: what you appear to be trying to do is a reshape. It doesn't make sense here, because rows should be your observations. if you reshape the data like you propose, then you would pair the data for two subject in the same row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to challenge your initial assumption that the data needs to be reshaped to generate a plot illustrating the effects of dose via both methods. It sounds like the use of groups and faceting in `ggplot2` can get you what you want. For example:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(gpt) + facet_wrap(~ supp) + 
geom_boxplot(aes(x = factor(dose), y = len, group = dose)) + 
labs(x = "Dose", y = "Len")
```